# Cluster nodes in a DAG without creating a cycle

Tags: cluster-analysis, graph-theory, partitioning, directed-acyclic-graphs

Let G = (V,E) be a [Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (DAG), with nodes V and edges E, and let U be a subset of V. How do we find a clustering with the following requirements:

1. Only nodes V\U can be clustered;
2. The nodes in a cluster must be [connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)) in the graph [induced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph) by V\U;
3. The resulting clustered graph is a DAG;
4. Optimization: if nodes can be clustered, they must be clustered.

Problem: clustering can create cycles.

Example:
Let G = (V,E), with V = {a,b,c,d}, E = {a -> b, b -> c, a -> c, c -> d}, and U = {b}. We will look to cluster nodes that are connected in the subgraph H [induced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph) by V\U, i.e. H = ({a,c,d}, {a -> c, c -> d}). Nodes a, c and d are connected, but clustering these nodes into one node {a,c,d} will produce a cycle in G, i.e., G becomes ({b, {a,c,d}}, {b -> {a,c,d}, {a,c,d} -> b}) which contains a cycle.

How do we find a clustering without cycles, where nodes are clustered if they can be, e.g., ({a, b, {c,d}}, {a -> b, b -> {c,d}, a -> {c,d}}.

Comment: I didn't understand exactly what you ask, does all the connected vertexes have to be clustered and the question is if the induced graph is a DAG? or you can choose the clustering and want to find a clustering that makes a DAG?. If it's the second option, do you want any clustering or optimized by size or other parameter?

Comment: @shukiavraham, I am looking for an answer to the same question. I think that he wants to fuse nodes a and c only if the graph remains DAG.

Comment: @shukiavraham: I'm trying to choose a clustering, such that the resulting graph is again a DAG. The only requirement now is that if a group of nodes are connected, then they must be clustered.